# Problems with performing asynchronous serial requests in combination with Realm

Tags: swift, multithreading, asynchronous, realm

I would like to perform a set of serial asynchronous requests in combination with Realm.

The set of requests I want to process are used to update a remote server and are determined from an array of structs containing the object type and local uuid. The related objects are fetched from a Realm database and subsequently written to the server using Alamofire.

However, fetching the Realm objects result in an error (`Realm accessed from incorrect thread`).

```
func performAsyncRequest<T: Object>(objectType: T.Type, uuid: String, failure fail: (()->Void)? = nil, success succeed: @escaping () -> Void)->Void {

    let realm = try! Realm() 
    let dataObject = realm.objects(objectType).filter("uuid == %@", uuid).first!
    let parameters = self.toJson(item: dataObject)

    // ** The Realm error occurs when the Alamofire request is performed  **

    let urlRequest = self.getRequest(objectType: T.self, with: parameters) 
    self.alamoFireManager.request(urlRequest) // Perform POST request
        .responseString { response in
            if let status = response.response?.statusCode {
                if status >= 200 && status <= 299 {
                    succeed() // Is not reached in combination with DispatchSemaphore
                } else if status >= 400 && status <= 499 {
                    fail?() // Is not reached in combination with DispatchSemaphore
                }
            }
    }
}
```

**Edit**: The code below is edited after the answer below (where a previous problem with the serial Alamofire request is solved).

In order to perform the Alamofire requests serially, `OperationQueue` is used in combination with `DispatchSemaphore`.

```
    let operationQueue = OperationQueue()
    var operation: Operation!

    for requestData in requests { // requestData is a struct with the object Type and a uuid
        switch requestData.objectType {
            case is Object1.Type:
                operation = BlockOperation(block: {
                    let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 0)
                    self.performAsyncRequest(objectType: Object1.self, uuid: requestData.uuid, failure: { error in
                           semaphore.signal()
                       }) {
                       semaphore.signal()
                    }
                    semaphore.wait()
                })
            case is Object2.Type:
                    // ... same as for Object1 but now for Object2

            // .. and so on for other Objects                
            }
        operationQueue.addOperation(operation)
    }
```

As indicated in the answer below the error occurs because Realm is thread confined. However, it is unclear to me why Realm instances are passed across different threads.

With an exception breakpoint I determined that the error occurs on thread `Queue: NSOperationQueue 0x… (QOS: UTILITY) (serial)`. This is a different thread from where `BlockOperation` is performed (and thus where the Realm objects are fetched). Why are the methods inside `BlockOperation` not performed on the same thread as `NSOperationQueue`?

I would appreciate any ideas to handle these problems.

Comment: rxSwift can be a better approach https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift

Comment: This is a good suggestion and I worked through all documentation. However, the issue remains that Realm is thread confined, which also needs to be assured when using RxSwift.

Comment: Have a look at this other question, we may have a duplicate here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/28646323/563802

Answer (score 0):

Realm and Realm objects are thread confinement. You should retrieve new realm instances on each thread. Do not pass a Realm instance across other threads.

It seems the main thread stops due to waiting for the semaphore. Then Alamofire callbacks are executed on the main thread. So `semaphore.signal()` is never called because the main thread stops. Alamofire's `response*` methods can specify `queue` a callback is called.

Comment: I solved the first issue by implementing an `OperationQueue` on a separate operation queue in combination with a semaphore, but I have still problems with fetching Realm. I determined that the Realm error occurs on thread `Queue: NSOperationQueue … (QOS: UTILITY) (serial)`. However, this is a different thread from where `BlockOperation` is performed and the Realm objects are fetched. Do you know why the methods inside `BlockOperation` are not performed on the same `NSOperationQueue` thread? Or do you know how I can assure thread confinement in this situation? Many thanks...